# UIWebview doesn't open a few URL's

Tags: ios, webview

I have been using UIWebView in iOS. It shows up a few pages, but for some reason, it doesn't load anything for others.
They open just fine in the browser but not in the UIWebView. While researching, I encountered [error code]!=999, but I was not able to fix it with it.

Any specific reason? Can anyone help me solve this?

Nithin

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please? How do you set it up and tell it what to load? Which pages don't show up?

Comment: Are you URL encoding correctly (it's the most common mistake I make when adding parameters to a url!) Give an example of a URL that works and one that doesn't so we can compare them

Answer (score 0):

dean is probably right ... the URL encoding issue is not always obvious, but it definitely caused me a lot of grief in my early stages of iOS dev.